# Retrieve documents starting from a particular document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

From the following sorted collection in MongoDB, how do I create a new collection so that it contains all documents after the document that contains `{"hash": "b"}`

```
{"hash": "a", "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"},
{"hash": "b", "key1": "val3", "key2": "val4"},
{"hash": "c", "key1": "val5", "key2": "val6"},
{"hash": "d", "key1": "val7", "key2": "val8"}
```

So I'm trying to create a new collection that contains:

```
{"hash": "c", "key1": "val5", "key2": "val6"},
{"hash": "d", "key1": "val7", "key2": "val8"}
```

I can retrieve the doc that contains {"hash": "b"} using find() but that doesn't help me traverse the subsequent elements in the original collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand how you are sorting on the hash value correctly, then the following will do what you want:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{$match: {hash: {$gt: 'b'}}}, 
{$out: 'new'}])
```

Just replace the name of the collection and the new collection you want to put the results into (the `$out` operator specifies the latter).